# How create a nice plot of a graph model that includes node properties?

Tags: neo4j, r-neo4j

How to plot a graph model similar just like the one below? I am looking for pretty print of a graph model that includes node properties.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see here is Arrows: http://www.apcjones.com/arrows

For source code see: https://github.com/apcj/arrows

Comment: Thanks, I also found out that a connection between nodes is drawn by hovering the mouse slightly outside the edge of the node, then selecting it. Great tool.